# RegEx parsing eshop params with PHP

Tags: php, regex

sorry for my bad english. I have some params of ware in eshop like:

```
Mraznička
* Počet zásuvek mrazničky 3
* XXL zásuvka
* Mrazící výkon 4,5 kg/24 h

Rozměry balení:
Hmotnost (kg): 61.000
Výška (cm): 182.00
Šířka (cm): 64.00
Hloubka (cm): 71.00


Typ: volně stojící
Konstrukce chladničky: kombinovaná
Umístění mrazícího prostoru: mraznička dole
Změna otevírání dveří: ANO
Ovládání: mechanické-knoflíkové
Displej: bez displeje
Energetická třída: A++
```

There are three kind of block and I need to choose, which one is.

Conditions for types:

1) Text block begin with any letter, but NOT with *  and NOT ending with :, this line must be followed by new line(s) beg. with *

2) Text block begin with any letter, but not with *  and ending with :, this line must be followed by new line(s) NOT beg. with *

3) Line(or lines) begin with word(od word), then following char ":" and then following any othes word(or words)

Can you help me, how can I identify type of textblock? I need to check each textblock separately - parsing long text to block is allready done and works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any code you have worked on so far? It is easier to improve something than to make something completely new. :)

Answer (score 0):

Added a possible solution for the 3 cases with a link to a online regex tester tool.
Each of these regex will only match one case of the block types.
As a precondition I assumed that the blocks are always separated by empty lines.

**Edit**
Minor updated regex inspired by comment (that was posted as separate answer) case 2 and 3 can overlap thus the regex now force empty line before each block.

1) http://www.myregextester.com/?r=df2be635

```
^[\r\n]{1,2}(?:[^*].+[^:][\r\n]{1,2})(?:\*.+[\r\n]{1,2})+$
```

2) http://www.myregextester.com/?r=f903ae6d

```
^[\r\n]{1,2}(?:[^*].+:[\r\n]{1,2})(?:[^*\s].+[\r\n]{1,2})+$
```

3) http://www.myregextester.com/?r=17ed0af8

```
^[\r\n]{1,2}(?:[^*].+:.+[^:][\r\n]{1,2})(?:[^*\s].+[\r\n]{1,2})+$
```

For all three cases the result will be captured in matcher group [0]. The regex is composed of two non capturing groups for the first line and the following repeated list.

Comment: check out edited version of regex. for regex 3 at first I didn't understand the question where the typo "word(od word)" actually means "word(or words)". **Important** as mentioned in the answer an empty line before each block is now forced as a precondition to avoid overlapping of case 2 and 3

Comment: @Los Bollos: your "not working" example doesn't start with an empty line. This should be a precondition in order to get it working.